# Ability to whitelist AWS Lambda function with WAF or run Lambda in a VPC

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-vpc, amazon-waf

I am creating a status page using LambStatus https://lambstatus.github.io/ and would like to have the status of components update automatically via cloudwatch alarms. I have to limit traffic to the status page. I currently only have traffic whitelisted that originates from a VPN or from our VPC IP addresses. In a perfect world the cloudwatch alarm triggers SNS ----> Lambda function ---> curls the API endpoint to update the component.

I need to either place the Lambda in the VPC so that the HTTPS Patch comes from a set of IP addresses or discover some other way of whitelisting the VPC.

Lambda functions can have access to VPC resources but still exist in the default VPC. Is it possible for me to control the IP addresses of the lambda function or have some way to whitelist the lambda request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Lambda uses IP address from EC2 range if you're planning to use WAF, You need to add an explicit header in CURL and allow the request in WAF only if the header is present.

Since you mentioned about WAF, I assume the API endpoint is a public endpoint and accessible over a Public IP address.

In this case, the good option is to use Lambda in VPC.
Lambda to communication to a Public IP in a VPC environment , it needs to be launched a private subnet , you can choose a subnet which has default route to a NAT gateway, NAT gateway requires a Elastic IP address so all the traffic from Lambda would go by the NAT gateway and you can whitelist the NAT gateway IP.
I would not recommend using a NAT instance because I don't know the instance type and the number of requests.

Comment: This was exactly the correct route to go. I really appreciate the help!!! I also found a great article on this implementation. https://medium.com/financial-engines-techblog/aws-lambdas-with-a-static-outgoing-ip-5174a1e70245 for those who come across this in the future.